# Design and simulation of cross coupled oscillator in ADS

Tags: rf, circuit-design, oscillator, simulation, ads

I am currently designing a low power consumption and low phase noise VCO in ADS. But while performing the transient response I'm not getting the oscillating waveform in the output. I have attached the image of my circuit. Any help can be greatly appreciated.

[image: ]Circuit diagram]

Comment: All the nodes say there's -333 MV on them, you might want to look at that first. Then, **after** your DC voltages are all OK, you should add something to start-up the oscillation. The simulator thinks that the static (non oscillating) state is a perfectly fine solution and theoretically that is true. In the real world **noise** would start the oscillation. During TRAN simulations, the simulator ignores noise so the oscillator doesn't start. To solve: add a pulse current source across the tank, make it output a short current pulse of for example 1mA after some delay, that will start it.

Comment: and have the current source turn on with a time much less than the oscillation period; thus for 1GHz oscillator, turn on with 100picoSecond.

Comment: Thank-you for your reply. I have made changes in the design but yet there comes a problem because I don't know the parameters of BJT. Any idea how do I get the transistor parameters to make the design working .